# trying to pass this graphic subroutine, but having issues

Tags: vb.net, graphics, subroutine

currently have items that have been populated from a listview that print, and i have done this without subroutines, but i want to organize the code and put each part in its own subroutine.

ive tried putting it in a subroutine the way i did with other parts of code, but none of those parts had to do with graphics.

```
    Using p As New Pen(Color.Gray)
        Dim t As Graphics = e.Graphics
        p.DashStyle = DashStyle.Custom
        Dim pattern() As Single = {3, 4, 3, 4}
        p.DashPattern = pattern
        t.DrawLine(p, 415, 0, 415, 1100)
        t.DrawLine(p, 0, 535, 850, 535)
    End Using
```

This code basically draws dashed lines vertically and horizontally on the page and it works, but i want to be able to call it from a subroutine.

when i put it in a subroutine like i have previously, getting errors passing e as graphics, no idea what that means or how to get around it, i searched on the forums here another person had similiar issue and i tried to follow those steps, the build compiled but when i ran it, it did not print the lines.

Answer (score 2):

Your subroutine could look like this,

```
Private Sub DrawDashes(g As Graphics)
    Using p As New Pen(Color.Gray)
        p.DashStyle = DashStyle.Custom
        Dim pattern() As Single = {3, 4, 3, 4}
        p.DashPattern = pattern
        g.DrawLine(p, 415, 0, 415, 1100)
        g.DrawLine(p, 0, 535, 850, 535)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Call like

```
DrawDashes(e.Graphics)
```

Comment: OMG that worked!!! thanks bud, im gonna convert all my graphics to subroutines,thx again.